# Nant task sysinfo verbose - fails

Tags: nant

Nant.core.dll : 0.86.2898.0

I can not get the following tag working on my machine.

```
  <sysinfo verbose="true" />
  <sysinfo />
```

It gives me the following error. If I comment out those two lines I'm able to build. I google'd but not much help. Any idea?

```
NAnt 0.85 (Build 0.85.1932.0; rc3; 4/16/2005)
Copyright (C) 2001-2005 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///C:/xyz/source/Default.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1
Target(s) specified: all

   [tstamp] Thursday, July 30, 2009 3:10:24 PM.
  [sysinfo] Setting system information properties under sys.*

BUILD FAILED

Property name 'sys.env.Zen Managed Workstation' is invalid.

Total time: 0 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Environment variables on your PC, as the  command loads these into working memory for use with your scripts. Maybe you have an environment variable in there that's badly defined, etc, that is confusing NAnt?

Also, do you know that you're running that command twice?   and